# How can I transfer offline songs from Spotify into a dual app of spotify to access downloaded music

Tags: music, cache, spotify

I am from a country where Spotify is not supported so I have installed it using vpn. I am using the 7 day premium trial which allows one to download and access music files. Can I reinstall the app and transfer spotify cache from previous version to the cache of the new app and access the music files?